# Do Riemann surfaces always have a unique compactification?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I suppose this question has two parts -

(1) Which Riemann surfaces have a compactification?

(2) If a Riemann surface has a compactification, is it necessarily unique?

Some references/sketch of the argument proving this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

- will

Comment: It seems as though this, and related questions, are not exactly easy to answer, see here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58947/is-a-non-compact-riemann-surface-an-open-subset-of-a-compact-one.